# Replacing variable with a generator of itself

Tags: python, generator

Maybe that's a stupid question but I wondered why this actually works:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
a = a.items() # or .iteritems() on python2 # or even a = (i for i in a)

b = [i for i in a]
b
[('b', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Why can I replace the variable with a generator over the variable? Doesn't this delete the actual contents of the original dict? How come that it still knows what was in that variable?

Because trying

```
a['a'] # before creating b
```

results in a `TypeError` because

> 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Are you asking how the generator knows what values to iterate across given that generators don't pull all the values they traverse into memory, so how is it they know what to do once you overwrite the original values?

Comment: @IanAuld - I think so. I had real trouble formulating the question and I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But I wondered: the generator is just told where to iterate over so if I delete the original (or overwrite it) how does the generator still knows what to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `a` is not assigned to until the expression is evaluated.  That is, `a.items()` is evaluated as a generator, and then `a` is assigned to it.  The generator has not been changed just because `a` no longer references the dictionary.  The dictionary still exists; it just isn't called `a` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
type(a) #before creating b
```

you will get

```
=> <class 'dict_items'>
```

Remember that a.items() returns a copy. From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
dict.items(): Return a view object of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs.
```

You lost reference to your dictionary when you assigned

```
a = a.items()
```

Comment: ok, I've just used ``dict.items()`` as example, why does it still work if you replace it with ``a = (key for key in a)`` - which is a generator?

Comment: because 
    
    a = (key for key in a)  

returns a generator

Comment: but the point about generators is that they don't save/return a copy.

Comment: yeah, that's why if you using a generator with a loop, you can use the 'yield' keyword to just pass that item. It works like an iterator, but for each time you loop, it returns an item.

Comment: @jmugz3: We're talking about Python 3.x here. The documentation for `items` says: "Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs)."

Comment: I fixed the link, but the built-in type hasn't changed.

Comment: I'm still irritated by the answer. Is it because it returns a copy that the data is still accessable? I think zondos answer is more precise about that there is still a reference and therefore the initial dict will not be deleted as long as the generator is not deleted.

Comment: You're returning to a dictionary so yeah the dictionary will still be available but since your replace the name of it, now the dictionary exists without a name. And only referenced through the generator